# How to batch add logos to different images

Tags: batch-processing, photoshop, photoshop-script, image-editing

i have almost 5k different logos and also have 5k different images, i want to add them up, is there any tool or way to do this.

I have seen tool which add one logo to all images, but it don't work with my scenario, i need a tool or way which allow me to multiple logos to add on multiple files, for example

- image 1 + logo1.jpg= image and logo1.jpg
- image 2 + logo2.jpg= image and logo2.jpg

and soo one.
is there way to do this work quickly instead of editing every pic manually

Comment: You should be able to have a script iterate through all the images and logos, open them and copy one onto the other. things to consider are: How will the script "know" which image goes with which logo? Are the size and resolutions of all the images and logos the same? If not should the script eresize the logo and if yes how? Where should the logo be positioned on the image. The [documentation on this page](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) can get you started

Comment: You could almost certainly do this very quickly and easily with ImageMagick but unfortunately your question gives no details of your operating system, how/where or what size the logos are to be added and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by creating actions and then using batch actions on folders containing the files.  If you sort all the images you want to have logo1 into their own folder, you can use a batch action to add the logo to every image in the folder and then save the new image as a jpg in a different folder.

Here is [a short youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgVmYauqOyA) explaining batch actions, and here is [a much longer, more detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYXRBEKp4Uo) that's officially from Adobe.  If you don't like videos, [this page explains the process with graphics](https://www.thoughtco.com/create-action-for-batch-processing-in-photoshop-1702309).

In short, here's what I would do:

1. Sort all the images you want to have logo 1 into a folder.
2. Open logo 1.
3. Select all and copy the logo.
4. With your logo still on the clipboard, open the first image.
5. Go to Windows --> Actions
6. Hit the little paper peeling icon to create a new action
7. Hit the record button to record your action and name it something you can remember later.
8. Paste your logo, and place it where you want it.
9. Go to Layers -> Flatten Image
10. Stop recording (or you might record how you save, but this doesn't always work.  If you do save, don't save over your original, rename it!)
11. Go to File -> Automate -> Batch, and choose the action you just saved, and select the folder you want to save the new logo-ified images into.
12. Carefully set all the save options
13. Click Run!

If you get prompted to choose color options on every save, you might want to redo the action so it includes (or does not include) "save as" options.

This is the short version of the answer.  I'm sure there are ways to script it, too, but this may be easier if you're not familiar with scripting.